# Printing the changes made on my list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, innerhtml

I need help to be able to print changes made on my list.
When I print the list, it works but, if we click on item, the hook don't show in preview or in printed page !

My css:

```
    .ulliminus {padding: 0 !important;}
    .ulliminus li {list-style: outside none none;}
    .css-label {background: #ffdddb none repeat scroll 0 0; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px !important;margin-left: -16px; height: 11px; width: 11px;border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);line-height:15px;}
    .css-checkbox:checked + .css-label::before {content: "\f00c";float: left;font-family: fontawesome; line-height: 10px;color: #477cb2;}
```

My html:

```
<ul class="accordion">
     <li id="printone" class="accordion__item">
<div data-id="541" class="underline-list__item js-accordion-open">
<div class="underline-list__link">
<div class="underline-list__text">title<span class="accordion_button"><span class="accordion_button_icon"></span></span></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion__content js-accordion-content">
<div class="wysiwyg">
<ul class="ulliminus">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid1e" class="css-checkbox"><label for="checkboxid1e" class="css-label"></label>1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid2e" class="css-checkbox"><label for="checkboxid2e" class="css-label"></label>2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid3e" class="css-checkbox"><label for="checkboxid3e" class="css-label"></label>3</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printone')" value="print a div!" />
</div>
</div>
</li></ul>
```

Now, I use the code snippet below and it almost works but, I have problems.

```
function printDiv(divId){
var originalContent = $('body').html();
var printcontent = $('#' + divId).clone();
$('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./style.css'/>");
$('body').empty().html(printcontent);
window.print();
document.location.reload(true);
$('body').html(originalContent);
}
```

With that one, the checkmarks appears but some css styles are missing.

Maybe not perfect, but it works !

Now, I need to find a way to adjust the css of the print or a way to add my own stylesheet.

Comment: Please add snippet or fiddle.

Comment: @Daniel Cheung , I found a new code snippet, who looks better, now I only need a way to adjust the css !

Comment: Ok, I think I find a way with this: `$('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=..../style.css'/>");`

Comment: Now when I print, my hidden div is empty. :(

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle to make it more clear ! https://jsfiddle.net/5e9p0ob3/7/